# Helping delete a folder in the registry

Tags: google-chrome

In my chrome settings, it is constantly saying "browser Managed by organisation" and the only way I have discovered to remove this is by deleting the chrome folder in policies of the Local Machine fold in registry editor.
Is there any way to automatically delete this folder perhaps daily?

Comment: Yes, just create bash script which will run periodically.

Comment: @kosist could you possibly make one? I have no idea how to

Comment: Here are some examples - https://superuser.com/questions/380156/delete-registry-key-or-value-via-a-cmd-script

Comment: @kosist I have no knowledge about this, could you refer me to have someone make me one, please.